# Keyboard management blocking UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitextfield

So I followed apple guidelines on moving text above the keyboard, this works fine when the textfields are on scrollview, however the scrollview contains a collection view and that collection view loads a nib with textfields populated within it, they are all assigned as the delegate and when they are pressed the didEdit/endEdit functions of the delegate do fire however the keyboard management code doesn't work as expected... here is the keyboard management code

```
http://creativecoefficient.net/swift/keyboard-management/
```

heres a link to the code am using..

```
func keyboardWillBeShown(sender: NSNotification) {
    print("KEYBOARD SHOWN")

    let info: NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
    let value: NSValue = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = value.CGRectValue().size
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    print(keyboardSize.height)
    ScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    ScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.


    var aRect: CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    let activeTextFieldOrigin: CGPoint? = activeTextFieldRect?.origin
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeTextFieldOrigin!)) {
    let dHeight = displayView.frame.height

    ScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeTextFieldRect!, animated:true) 
}
```

The problem with this code is that the activeTextfield works well with the textfields of the view, i get these points printed when i click on the textfield

```
activetextfield Frame
(0.0, 20.5, 150.0, 20.5)
```

but when i click on the collection view nib textfields i get these points

```
0.0, 0.0, 259.5, 30.0
```

I believe this is the reason the keyboard is blocking the textfields, the activetextfieldRect is giving the wrong coordinates to

```
ScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeTextFieldRect!, animated:true)
```

can someone give me some direction on how to go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. `scrollRectToVisible` receive wrong coordinates, and this is why it is not work.

To achieve your goal consider using [scrollToItemAtIndexPath(_:atScrollPosition:animated:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:). All what you need is `IndexPath` of cell to move. And I guess you can put that info in `tag` property of your `textField` (for instance).

Something like this:

```
// inside cellForItem..
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.item

// inside keyboardWillShown
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: activeTextField.tag inSection: 0) // assume that you have one section
collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .Top, animated: true) // or try .Center position
```

Comment: the problem here is that you can only see one index path at a time (quite large) n all the textfields have the same index path.item Num, i have got this working a different way, will post answer soon, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
func keyboardWillBeShown(sender: NSNotification) {
    print("KEYBOARD SHOWN")
    let info: NSDictionary = sender.userInfo!
    let value: NSValue = info.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = value.CGRectValue().size
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0)
    ScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    ScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    // If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
    // Your app might not need or want this behavior.
    var aRect: CGRect = self.ScrollView.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height
    let activeTextFieldRect: CGRect? = activeTextField?.frame
    let activeTextFieldOrigin: CGPoint? = TextfieldPoint
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeTextFieldOrigin!)) {


        ScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(testBox, animated:true)
    }

       }

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
func keyboardWillBeHidden(sender: NSNotification) {
    print("KEYBOARD HIDDEN")
    let contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    ScrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    ScrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {



    let point: CGPoint = textField.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.ScrollView);

TextfieldPoint = point

    testBox = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, textField.frame.width, 100 );

    //let indexPath:NSIndexPath? = collview1.indexPathForItemAtPoint(point)

    print("TEXTFIELD EDIT")
    activeTextField = textField

    print(activeTextField)





    ScrollView.scrollEnabled = true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

    print("TEXTFIELD STOP EDIT")
    activeTextField = nil
    ScrollView.scrollEnabled = false
}
```

it works just really messy i guess, i got the point where textfield was, made CGRect out of it, if the keyboard overlaps the text, the view adjusts, tested on iPhone 4s to 6s plus, works fine